# How do I know which one is the physical MAC Address programmatically?

Tags: vb6, virtualbox, mac-address

I use this code in `VB6` to get the `MAC Address` of the computer:

```
Sub GetMACAddress()

    'get MAC address using WMI
    Dim oWMIService As Object
    Dim oColAdapters As Object
    Dim oObjAdapter As Object

    Set oWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "!\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set oColAdapters = oWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True")

    For Each oObjAdapter In oColAdapters
       MsgBox "MAC address formatted: " & oObjAdapter.MacAddress & vbNewLine _
       & "MAC address unformatted: " & Replace(oObjAdapter.MacAddress, ":", "")
    Next

    Set oObjAdapter = Nothing
    Set oColAdapters = Nothing
    Set oWMIService = Nothing
    End Sub
```

The problem is that I have Windows 7 running on Oracle VirtualBox installed and `oColAdapters` is having two MAC Addresses.

How to check which one is the phisical one of my PC?

Comment: I have an ethernet port and a wifi module in my computer. They obviously have different MACs. How do I check which one is the physical one of my PC?

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish? Maybe if you explain the larger problem you are working on we will understand better what you need to do?